# He said, I can't solve this riddle

Tags: riddle

> I come with a sigh
> I gave me a new name
> In Spain I fly
> Without a I'm the

What word am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word is

> **alas**

*I come with a sigh*

> **[Alas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alas#English)**, an expression of regret, is often said with a sigh.

*I gave me a new name*

> Add **i** to get **alias**, a new name.

*In Spain I fly*

> **[Alas](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alas#Spanish)** is Spanish for "wings".

*Without a I'm the*

> Remove the **a** and **las** is Spanish for "the".

Comment: Nice job! The title is also a little bit of a clue and can be stretched two be a sort-of double clue.

Comment: Nice riddle! I'll keep working on the title...

Comment: Thanks! The title is a little more hint than clue.